# Resources for Entity Framework using an Effective Date Pattern

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

What are the best practices for modeling point in time data using an effective date pattern and Entity Framework 6? I'm having trouble finding resources on the topic.

The solution has to perform extremely fast. Thus, my concern in the design and why I'm seeking anyone with experience to point out some resources.

The Linq query is not terribly hard, but at the same time it needs to be faster and cleaner than the average Entity Framework auto generated SQL is. Stored procedures are something we avoid so that no application logic is hidden in the database, but in this case performance is more important.

An example of the SQL that we currently use in the system we are replacing:

```
SELECT  [P].[Id],
    [P].[EffectiveDate],
    [P].[Column1],
    [P].[Column2],
    [P].[Column3],
    [P].[Column4]
FROM    [PointInTime] [P]
WHERE   [P].[EffectiveDate] = ( SELECT  MAX([P1].[EffectiveDate])
                            FROM    [PointInTime] [P1]
                            WHERE   [P1].[Id] = [P].[Id]
                                    AND [P1].[EffectiveDate] <= GETUTCDATE()
                          );
```